# How to get a connection to the gitlab API in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, oauth-2.0, gitlab

I have to build an application using WPF interacting with Gitlab (any instance). I have difficulties with the connection.

I use this library: https://github.com/nmklotas/GitLabApiClient but apparently Gitlab requires a secret  `client_id` and `client_secret`, and this was not supposed to be the case before.

- Option 1:
  Use username/password to get a token. The problem is that I need an `client_id` and a `client_secret`. The problem is that I don't have this information for all gitlab instances.
- Option 2:
  Ask the user for an `access_token`. This solution should work, but is not practical, so use it as a last resort.
- Option 3:
  Maybe it's possible with a webview to get a token, but I don't know if it's feasible or how to use the url callback.

Thank you for your help.